# Defining meromorphic functions and forms on a Riemann surface using a single formula in a single chart

Tags: differential-forms, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

I am working out of Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces. In the book, we define differential forms for a Riemann surface to be a collection of forms satisfying a compatibility condition {$\omega_\phi\ | \ \phi:U\rightarrow V \text{ a chart in the complex structure for }X$}. We then show it suffices it to define a form over a collection of charts that cover $X$. Later on, the author writes the following:

> The definition of a meromorphic or holomorphic 1-form $\omega$ suggests that in order to define $\omega$ on a Riemann surface $X$, one must give local expressions for $\omega$ (of the form $f(z)dz$) in each chart of an atlas for $X$. In fact, one can define $\omega$ by giving a *single* formula in a *single* chart. This is sufficient to determine $\omega$ by the Identity Theorem for meromorphic functions and forms: if two meromorphic 1-forms agree on an open set, they must be identical.

My difficulty is unpacking why this statement is true. I understand the statement of the Identity Theorem, but I don't see how one can apply it in this situation. Here is the line of thought that I have attempted so far.

'Define' a holomorphic 1-form $f(z)dz$ on some chart $\phi_1:U_1\rightarrow V_1$, where $p\mapsto z$. Now grab a chart with non-trivial intersection with $\phi_2$, say $\phi_2:U_2\rightarrow V_2$, where $p\mapsto w$. All we can do at this point is to extend our 1-form by defining it using the transformation formula with $T=\phi_1\circ \phi_2^{-1}$ to obtain $g(w)dw:=f(T(w))T'(w)dw$ for the chart $\phi_2$. However, if I am understanding things correctly, this extension isn't really an extension because the new form $g(w)dw$ is only defined on $\phi_2^{-1}(U_1\cap V_2)$. I imagine that this is where the Identity Theorem is supposed to be leveraged, but I am not seeing where we can apply it.

**Edit:**
Maybe adding some motivation for the question can clarify what I am getting at. Let $X$ be a smooth affine plane curve defined by $f(u,v)=0$. We want to show that $du$ and $dv$ define holomorphic 1-forms on $X$.
Examining $du$, let $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ be a chart where $\partial f / \partial v$ is non-zero on $U$ so that via the invertible function theorem $\phi: (u,v)\mapsto u$ is indeed a chart. Then we can define on this chart the 1-form $\omega=1du$.The transition maps can't take things outside of of the set $U$, since they are only possibly defined on intersections of $U$ with other sets - so how can one actually extend it past that?

Comment: I’d need to see the text to be sure, but I think the result refers only to *uniqueness*, that is: if two meromorphic $1$-forms of the surface are the same in one chart, by the identity theorem they are equal. So, if you *know* that your differential is globally defined (except on finitely many points where it has poles), it’s enough to give a formula in one chart to specify which it is.

Comment: @Mindlack What I quoted was verbatim, so I think the author really does mean that "one can define $\omega$ by giving a single formula in a single chart" where $\omega$ is supposed to be a mero/holo 1-form on the surface. The reason why this is giving me a headache is that the problem sets have you work with forms defined using a single formula for a single chart. For example, one is given $X$ as a smooth projective plane curve defined by $F(x,y,z)=0$ and is supposed to show that d$u$ and d$v$ (defined on one specific chart) are actually mermorphic 1-forms on the whole surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$If $\omega_{j}$ is a meromorphic $1$-form in an open set $U_{j}$ for $j = 1$, $2$, and if $\omega_{1} = \omega_{2}$ on the *intersection* $U_{1} \cap U_{2}$, then we have a meromorphic $1$-form on the *union* $U_{1} \cup U_{2}$; agreement of the representatives on the intersection guarantees well-definedness. Further, the $1$-form $\omega_{1}$ has *at most one* extension to $U_{1} \cup U_{2}$ by the identity theorem.

In the case of an affine plane curve, $\omega_{1} = du$ is holomorphic in $U_{1} = \{\dd f/\dd v \neq 0\}$. Since
$$
\frac{\dd f}{\dd u}\, du + \frac{\dd f}{\dd v}\, dv = 0
$$
everywhere on the curve, we have $du = -\frac{\dd f/\dd v}{\dd f/\dd u}\, dv$ in $U_{2} = \{\dd f/\dd u \neq 0\}$. If the curve is non-singular, these open sets cover, so we're in the situation of the preceding paragraph. Practically, we proceed as if $du$ is globally defined.

**Added**: At a point $p$ where $\dd f/\dd u(p) = 0$, the holomorphic $1$-form $(\dd f/\dd v)\, dv$ vanishes. The "culprit" turns out to be $dv$, which annihilates every tangent vector at $p$: Think of a graph having a horizontal tangent, so every tangent vector at $p$ has $v$-component zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I might be misunderstanding the formula $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\, du + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\, dv = 0$, though. I understand that this comes from taking the differential of the defining equation $f(u,v)=0$, but it seems to imply to me that $U_1=U_2$ when the curve is non-singular. If $\partial f / \partial u(p)=0$ then by that equation $0du + \partial f / \partial v(p)dv = 0$ implying that $\partial f / \partial v (p) = 0$ which contradicts the non-singularity of the curve. What am I missing here?

Comment: Also, I don't want to discredit the author by the omission in my quote, so I want to point out that they do clarify later that a locally defined 1-form does not necessarily extend to a global one. I believe the example given was exp(z)dz on the affine patch of the Riemann sphere, which does not extend to a open neighborhood of $\infty$.

Comment: It's actually the "$dv$" that vanishes at $p$ (that is, annihilates every tangent vector at $p$) where $\partial f/\partial u = 0$, not the coefficient. :)

Comment: I'll edit my infelicitous late-night wording momentarily....