# Smooth affine plane curve: Differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, algebraic-curves, affine-geometry

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Let $f(u,v)$ be a smooth bivariate polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{C}^2\vert f(u,v)=0\}$ be the corresponding affine smooth plane curve. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168178/defining-meromorphic-functions-and-forms-on-a-riemann-surface-using-a-single-for) answer by Andrew D. Hwang it is claimed that on $X$ we have

$$
\frac{\dd f}{\dd u}\, du + \frac{\dd f}{\dd v}\, dv = 0.
$$

Why is that true? It seems to somehow come from "differentiating" the defining equation of $X$. I am struggling to derive the details. My definition of differentials is taken from Forster's "Lectures on Riemann Surfaces".

EDIT: In Forster's book the differential is defined as follows. Let $f$ be a smooth function on an open subset $U$ of a Riemann surface. Let $a\in U$. Then the differential of $f$ at $a$ is defined as
$d_af:=(f-f(a))\operatorname{mod} \mathsf{m_a}^2 \in T^{(1)}_a$. Here $T^{(1)}_a:=\frac{\mathsf{m_a}}{\mathsf{m_a}^2}$ denotes the cotangent space at $a$, where $\frac{\mathsf{m_a}}{\mathsf{m_a}^2}$ is the quotient vector space of the vector space $\mathsf{m_a}$ of function germs at $a$ that vanish at $a$ and the vector subspace $\mathsf{m_a}^2\subset \mathsf{m_a}$ of function germs at $a$ that vanish at $a$ to the second order.

Comment: Can you add your definition of differentials to your post? It's much easier to answer a question when you provide the definition. (For instance, I don't have a personal copy of this book, so if I wanted to write an answer, I would either have to guess at the definition [bad, what if I use a different definition than you do] or wait to go to the library, find the book in the stacks, note the definition, and then come back to this post [a bunch of effort on my part]. It's much less total work and therefore an answer is more likely to happen if you add the definition.)

Comment: @KReiser Edited. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, that's helpful - the answer I had started writing would not have been for that definition, haha. I'd suggest differentiating both sides of the equation $f=0$, which holds on $X$.

Comment: Since you’re talking about affine plane curves, you need to specify that $X$ is the zero-set of $f$. This is far from obvious.

Comment: @KReiser I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @TedShifrin Edited.